# Flutter detect div class or id inside webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview

there is any way to detect a div click inside a webview and do some action.
Like this:

`if (request.url.contains("mailto:")`

But with a Div or Span ...

Answer (score 0):

I only use flutter mobile but there is a widget called gesturedectetion

It has a tap method.  You set it as a parent to the widgets you want to capture taps.